# Latex vertical text in header

Tags: tables, rotating

I am relatively new in latex and would like to create a table which is built as follows in the picture.

[image]

Would be nice if I could get support for my concern

Comment: You can use \rotatebox{90}{some text} to rotate text in 90 degree and \multicolumn{}{}{} commands​ to get above table @Hannez Os

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable code?